# Hash table vs. Sorted Array - which to use?

Tags: arrays, performance, data-structures, hash, complexity-theory

Suppose I have a set of data (unsorted) that I want to store for quick lookup. I don't know what the size is before I load the data and I should load it all at once so I can start performing lookups right away.

In addition, at any time during program execution more data may be presented to me to be stored in the data structure I choose.

Should I use a hash table or sorted array to store this data? Obviously a static hash table would require being made at runtime according to the size of data presented - would this be enough of a disadvantage that I should simply sort the data given to me, even though it would be O(NlogN) instead of O(N)? Or should I be considering some method of dynamic hashing?

**Clarification**: I need to load data of arbitrary size and then perform search and insertions on the data, with no clear order or idea of the amount of searching/inserting I'll have to do.

I know that's really general...but what if I have to do more insertions after loading the data than searches? What about more searches than insertions?

Comment: There is no clear answer to this question - it completely depends on your use case.  Can you elaborate more on what operations you need to support?

Comment: I added a clarification - hope that helps

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This really depends on the frequency of the operations.

- If you do a lot of insertions relative to the number of lookups, then a sorted array is probably not a good option because inserting into a sorted array is expensive (O(n) time).  A binary search tree or hash table might be appropriate here.
- If you do a huge number of lookups relative to the number of insertions, then a sorted array might be a good idea, though a hash table is likely to be faster.  Sorted arrays are usually a good choice when you need the data to be in sorted order to do operations like range searches or nearest-neighbor lookups, but if you don't need to do that, it's probably not appropriate.
- If your keys are of certain types (integers, strings, etc.) you might be able to use a more specific data structure like a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or [van Emde Boas tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree) to get extra performance.  These are sometimes better choices than hash tables or sorted arrays because they can take advantage of the specifics of your data.

If you honestly don't know what's going to happen, I would use a hash table as an initial implementation.  It's unlikely to be a bad choice, though there might be a more fine-tuned data structure you could use instead.  The sorted array is unlikely to be a good idea if you don't know the usage pattern in advance.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

Templatetypedef's answer is spot on, but I'll add some more info on RedBlack Trees which offer a nice compromise between both of your options.  He mentioned tries and vEB trees (haven't heard of the latter before, sounds useful!) RedBlack Trees are less optimal than those options, but possibly a more general solution.  Certainly worth looking into these more elegant tree structure options as well as lists or hash maps.

```
RedBlack Tree:
Insertion: O(log n)
Key Lookup: O(log n)
Key Search: O(log n)
Iteration: O(n)

Sorted List:
Insertion: O(n log n)
Index Lookup: O(1)
Sorted Search: O(log n)
Iteration: O(n)

Hash Table:
Insertion: O(1)
Key Lookup: O(1)
Key Search: O(n)
Iteration: O(n)
```

Comment: Good additional information! I hadn't considered R/B trees - I'll need to do some time testing with those vs. hashing.

Comment: btw, what the difference between `key lookup` and `key search`?

Comment: @Kokizzu Good quesiton, I realize that's not terribly clear.  "Key Lookup" refers to accessing the value of a known key.  "Key Search" refers to finding the closest key; a sorted structure can do this efficiently, however a Hash Table requires checking every key.